# panel-body not displaying full width when display set to inline-block

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make to panel-body div adjust to screen resolution when its 'display' is set to 'inline-block'? The panel-body div displayed full width when its 'display' set to 'block', which can cause other problems.

HTML code:

```
<div class="panel-body">
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
</table>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.panel-body {
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  display: inline-block;
}

.table
{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Notice that if set 'min-width:1100px;' to the table CSS, the table width is fixed, not able to adjust to the screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
.panel-body {
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table{
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;/*Remove this*/
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #ff0;/*Remove this*/
}
```

[CodePen sample of code](http://codepen.io/zlajaa1/pen/eNZoOm)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for outer div is responsive and the inner table with some width...

```css
.panel-body {
   width: 96%;
  padding: 2%;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  overflow-x: auto;
  
}

.table
{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-body">
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>Sample data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```